# why is http response.body empty

Tags: http, httpresponse

Whilst write tests for my express API I wanted to check that `response.body` had the html I expected in it. 
I found that the response object has a body property but that it is empty. I found the html in the `response.text` property. 
When I used Postman to examine the response, it uses the words header for the header details and body for the html data. This is what I expected. This difference is confusing me as I am just learning http. 
I am not asking about my own code as I tried it with a different site (www.bbc.co.uk) and got the same thing.
Why is there a difference in the wording? What is `response.body` for if not the data being returned?

Here is the code used in my test. This is the ejs template;

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>Hello again world!</body>
</html>
```

Here is the express app;

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.status(200).render('index');
});

app.get('*', function(req, res){
    res.status(404).send('what???');
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Example app listening on port ' + port);
});
```

Here are the tests;

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
const expect = require('chai').expect;
chai.use(chaiHttp);

const api = 'www.bbc.co.uk';

describe('The phonics API', () => {
    it('should return status', (done) => {
        chai.request('http://localhost:3000')
            .get('/')
            .end((err, res) => {
                expect(res).to.have.status(200);
                expect(res.body).to.exist;
                done();
            });
    });

    it('should return an HTML file in the body', (done) => {
        chai.request('http://localhost:3000')
            .get('/')
            .end((err, res) => {
                expect(res).to.be.html;
                done();
            });
    });

    it('should return status 404 for wrong url', (done) => {
        chai.request('http://localhost:3000')
            .get('/resersa')
            .end((err, res) => {
                expect(res).to.have.status(404);
                done();
            });
    });

    it('should respond with a body', (done) => {
        chai.request(api)
        .get('/')
            .end((err, res) => {
                expect(res.body).to.exist;
                console.log(res.body);
                done()
            });
    });
});
```

In the last test I added `console.log(res.body)` to see what was there. It prints `{}`. When I change it to `console.log(res.test)` I get the html above.

When I use postman to `GET http://localhost:3000` It has the html under a tab called body.

Comment: Are we talking about nodejs' express? If so then what version.

Comment: Please show the code you use to do the request and inspect the .body property - it will make it a lot easier to have some common ground to talk about.

Comment: I added my code, but I would like to draw your attention to the fact, as mentioned, I tried it on the BBC website and had the same thing.